# Python list comprehension issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

What am I missing here.

I have a list of dictionaries.

```
lod = [{'name': 'storm', 'age': 99}]
```

I want to add a key to each item in the list, so i do the following

```
lod = [r.update({ 'new_key': 'new_value'}) for r in lod]
```

but the resulting lod becomes `None`

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.update` is a mutating function, it is modifying the original dict. By default python functions return `None`, hence when calling `update` it is returning nothing so `None`.

The way to do this is simple, use a for loop instead:

```
for r in lod:
    r.update({"new_key": "new_value"})
```

Comment: You probably meant mutating function, not mutable function.

Comment: @timgeb, yes, exactly